# Complex encryption/decryption model - is this even possible?

Tags: java, security, scala, encryption, public-key-encryption

Suppose I have a server which is publishing information (e.g. via a message bus) to four parties: A, B, C and D. All traffic can be discovered in encrypted form by any party. In order to make use of the information, obviously it would need to be decrypted:

- Party A should be able to read all information (i.e. decrypt information intended for A, B and C)
- Party B should be able to read information intended for B and C
- Party C should only be able to read information intended for party C
- Party D should be able to read information for B and D

Obviously this could be achieved by having completely separate public/private key pairs for each party and then sharing the private keys as per the requirements above. Unfortunately this *does not scale* nicely to hundreds of parties.

**Is there a better way?**

---

**EDIT**

*Basically, what I would like to do is for each person to have their private key and for me to say, when encrypting a message, that it is encrypted with `key = A | B | C` such that this means that a person with any of key A, B or C can decrypt it. Imagine a trunk which can have `n` locks fitted to it, any of which can open the trunk.*

Comment: Why does having separate key pairs not scale nicely for hundreds of parties? Is there a simple access control scheme for these hundreds of parties (such as ordering i.e. #47 can read messages intended for #47, #48 ....)?

Comment: @Thilo - Imagine a supermarket. Every single shelf is independently stockable. There are a hundred shelf stackers, each of whom stack a number of shelves. These stackers  have managers, who can overview the shelves of all of their subordinates. These stock managers have section managers possibly having complex relationships, such as manager A being able to see a subset of manager B's shelves. There are a few store managers who can see everything. **None of the shelf stackers, stock managers, section managers or store managers would have any kind of clue about public/private key cryptography**

Comment: Maybe the audience at security.stackexchange.com would be more knowledgable?

Comment: Why is this tagged Scala or even Java?

Comment: It would be nice if the "middle managers" could re-broadcast the messages to their subordinates. This is how it works in meat-space, I guess.

Comment: @ziggystar - because I am working in scala and/or Java. Some arcane C++ library is not going to be much use to me. But I agree, it's not specific to those languages

Comment: @lakes But this question doesn'T sound like the question for a library but at a theoretical level of "is this possible/a good idea".

Comment: i believe, session keys are the key to the effective solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want can be achieved using normal protocols based on public key cryptography.  The [Bouncy Castle Crypto APIs](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) has support for both [OpenPGP](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pgdocs1.6/index.html) and [CMS](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/mdocs1.6/index.html), either of which can work from Scala.

TO set everything up:

- Every party is given a public/private key pair.

  - No one EVER shares the private key.  The private key must stay private
- Every party knows every other party's public key

The protocols allow encryption using multiple public keys.  For example, if you use something like the [PGPEncryptedDataGenerator](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pgdocs1.6/org/bouncycastle/openpgp/PGPEncryptedDataGenerator.html), then you would call the [addMethod(PGPPublicKey)](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pgdocs1.6/org/bouncycastle/openpgp/PGPEncryptedDataGenerator.html#addMethod%28org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKey%29) method for every recipient you wish to be able to decrypt the message.

There are a lot of nuances to the API's, but the unit tests and examples will really help you navigate them.

*Implementation Details*

Both protocols work in fundamentally the same way.

1. Securely generate a random symmetric key
2. For every recipient, encrypt the symmetric key with the recipient's public key.  All of the encrypted public keys are written into a message header.
3. Encrypt the message using the symmetric key.  This becomes the message content.

Recipients reverse the process to decrypt the message

1. Search message header for key addressed to self.
2. Use private key to decrypt symmetric key.
3. Use symmetric key to decrypt the message content.

Comment: Ouch - that's exactly what I want, behaviour-wise but it may be too much of an overhead, even with a shallow tree. I will have to see! Thanks very much.

Comment: "Every party is given a public/private key pair" is also a critical point. I can hardly expect my shelf-stackers to generate their own. But how do I generate and distribute them in a safe way. And what happens when a shelf-stacker moves section, for example, and should have a key revoked?

Comment: You're right, it is complicated. You can do a lot of key generation automagically as a part of your application. Or you might be able to use an off-the-shelf certificate authority. Assuming that "shelf-stacker moves section" means that messages destined for a party should now be decryptable by a different set of parties, this shouldn't require a key revokation. You just encrypt new messages with a different set of recipients.

Answer (score 3):

> Imagine a supermarket. Every single shelf is independently stockable. There are a hundred shelf stackers, each of whom stack a number of shelves. These stackers have managers, who can overview the shelves of all of their subordinates. These stock managers have section managers possibly having complex relationships, such as manager A being able to see a subset of manager B's shelves. There are a few store managers who can see everything.

I don't think the scalability problem comes from using public-key crypto. It rather comes from the complexity in your requirement (wanting to have so many configurable groups).

If you are going to send out the same encrypted message to hundreds of parties, and there can be an arbitrary subset of them that are supposed to read it, and you want to be able modify these permissions later, you need to give everyone his own key-pair.

You would then send out the message encrypted symmetrically (with a random session key) along with copies of the session key encrypted for all recipients.

If you see that very often you address the exact same subset, you may extend the validity of those session keys to span multiple messages. Then you do not need to transmit all the keys every time (you should still expire them after some time, though).

> None of the shelf stackers, stock managers, section managers or store managers would have any kind of clue about public/private key cryptography

Well, their software/device would handle that.

Comment: Those "session keys" are roughly equivalent to @Wesley Hill's pre-distributed AES keys.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is simply no way I can re-publish the same message multiple times as my "shelf changed events" are rather frequent and are already throttled as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way that requires n key exchanges, but keeps the messages themselves as small as for two-party communication.

Assuming that the general form of your problem is:

- There are n parties, numbered p_1 through p_n
- Messages have a security level m, such that only parties p_1 to p_m can decrypt the message.

You can use this key exchange step:

- Generate n AES keys, numbered k_1 to k_n.
- Securely give each key k_i to all parties p_1 to p_i.

Then to send a message with security level m, just encrypt it with the key k_m.

One side-effect of this scheme is that party p_b does not have the ability to prevent party p_a from decrypting messages they send if a < b. Hopefully that's okay.

Comment: That would work with "security levels", but not with the "security tree" (or maybe even arbitrary recipient sets) that is apparently required here. +1 anyway.

Comment: I'm afraid my original description of the problem has confused matters; I do indeed have a tree, rather than a linear hierarchy

Answer (score -1):

Can you use custom encryption like Blowfish?
In such a case you can share the Blowfish encryption key and store it in a, let's say, a properties file!
When the data arrives, depending on the destination and the key value in properties file you can try decrypting them

Comment: But then everyone can decrypt it, not just a subset.